# iPhone, mistakenly fooled with VPN on to off. Now can't get back to On and no internet phone gmail or text on iPhone 4S

Tags: vpn

I foolishly clicked VPN to OFF. Now I can't get things back to the way it was before clicking that OFF. I have no internet, phone, text, gmail on my 4s iPhone now! Help! 
So, I cANNOT receive email from you now, either! I'm on desktop and can't get on as guest...

Comment: I don't see how disabling VPN would cause a lot of damage? What did you do exactly?

Comment: VPN turns off *every time you lock your phone*, so this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: As Rob and 0942v8653 told you, we need more indications about your problem because right now it is hard to understand it.

Comment: Sounds like the OP activated airplane mode inadvertently. VPN would have no affect on the wifi or phone radios.

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed VPN connection completely, it's easy to configure your VPN again. As I don't know the details of your VPN, here is very general PPTP configuration guide that could give you better idea of the procedure:

1. Choose **Settings** from your home screen.
2. Choose **General**
3. Choose **VPN**
4. Choose **Add VPN Configuration**
5. Choose **PPTP** at top of screen.
6. **Description =** whatever you wish, for eample: "VPN Connection"
7. **Server =** VPN server IP address or hostname.
8. **Account =** Enter your VPN Username
9. **Password =** Your VPN Password
10. **RSA SecurID =** OFF
11. **Encryption Level =** Auto
12. **Send all Traffic =** ON
13. **Proxy =** OFF
14. Click **SAVE** at the top

**Connecting and Disconnecting**

Just go to Settings and slide VPN selector to on. You will receive a welcome message and a VPN indicator will appear at the top of your device’s screen. To disconnect, go to Settings and slide indicator to off.

Hope it could help

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do, if you were fooled into the app hooked, is go into settings then general. From there, find profile and click delete account with hooked.